# Writing rational number as functions in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I actually have 2 questions (which I hope they are related). How can I turn rational numbers in a sympy expression to fractions. For example "0.25*x+0.5*y" I would like to became "1/4*x+1/2*y". The second question: If I want to replace a variable symbol by a fraction, the fraction gets automatically converted to a decimal number. For example for `eq = parse_expr("p1*cos(5*x)")` doing `eq = eq.subs("p1",1/5)` gives me 0.2cos(5) instead of 1/5*0.2cos(5). Of course they are both the same mathematically, but I would like to have them in a nicer, fractional form. How can I do that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Rational](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html?highlight=rational#sympy.core.numbers.Rational). In the first case, write

```py
Rational(0.25)*x + Rational(0.5)*y
```

or

```py
Rational(1, 4)*x + Rational(1, 2)*y
```

which gives you `x/4 + y/2`. In the second case,

```py
eq.subs("p1", Rational(1, 5))  # cos(5*x)/5
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are working in Python, every expression you write passes through Python semantics. So `1/5` becomes `0.25` before SymPy can do anything with it. This is covered in the 'gotchas.rst' file in the documentation.

The only time you will encounter this is when you have two leading numbers in a product  dividing each other as in `1/5*x` but not `x*1/5`. In such cases you can prevent them from becoming a Float by wrapping one of them in `S()` to make it a SymPy number rather than a Python number, e.g. `S(1)/5*x`. This proactive step is needed in all contexts where you use a numeric fraction alone or as the first factor in a product

```
>>> x.subs(x, 1/5)
0.2
>>> x.subs(x, S(1)/5)
1/5
```

If you happen to have an expression in which you want to convert the Floats back to Rationals you can use `nsimplify(..., rational=True)`:

```
>>> nsimplify(0.25*x + 0.5*y, rational=True)
x/4 + y/2
```